# Change default Roslyn project dlls version from 42.42.42.42 to 2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Any assembly that gets compiled from within Roslyn project has 42.42.42.42 version. Is there a way to change that? If I try to set it directly through project window I receive a runtime exception.

Comment: Interestingly, [searching for 42 in the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?q=42) gives a *lot* of results, particularly in tests. Seems the developers never leave home without a towel.

Comment: I have a personal belief that no test is complete unless it either has 'foo' or 42 in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build on the command line with `/p:OfficialBuild=true /p:BuildNumber=1234` or some other number.

Comment: What is actually the reason for a "weird" version number such as this (not specifically 42, I know that)? Is it to easily distinguish custom builds from released builds?

Comment: Yes, that's one reason. If somebody modifies Roslyn and crashes Visual Studio, we get the crash report if you have the option enabled in Windows. This lets us know it's not a "real" version and we can just throw it out right away.

Comment: The second reason is if you're running a modified Roslyn inside of Visual Studio, you are essentially running a second version atop VS that already has the first version installed. Due to the complexities of how the .NET framework loads assemblies in Visual Studio, it's easier to just install a second version (42!) and insert some redirects. It's also easier to verify the version you think you're running (your local copy) is then the one you are.